# How to install Eclipse Neon/Mars for C/C++ on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, eclipse

I have downloaded the related Eclipse `.tar` package from [here](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/keplersr2) to install on my `64 bit` machine. I followed the [instruction](http://stuff.stevenreid.uk/2015/06/29/install-eclipse-mars-for-cc-on-ubuntu-15-04-x32/), but does not seem to work. How to install the Eclipse Neon/Mars for C/C++ on ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you extracted the downloaded eclipse package and created a working eclipse.desktop launcher file, then your eclipse still needs at least an installed JRE (Java Runtime Environment) or an installed JDK (Java Development Kit - OpenJDK or OracleJDK) to work...

I would recommend you to install OracleJDK if you develop with Java as well, otherwise you only need the OracleJRE... I can post the instructions how to do this in a very clean way, if you need them...

Eclipse should locate your installed JRE/JDK automatically, if everything is installed properly...
alternatively you can tell eclipse, where to find the JRE/JDK:

open the **eclipse.ini** file with gedit (in your extracted eclipse folder) and edit it as follows:

```
...

openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs

# add these lines ----------------------------------------
-vm
/path-to-jre-or-jdk-folder/jdk1.8.0_version/bin
# --------------------------------------------------------

-vmargs

...
```

Replace 'path-to-jre-or-jdk-folder' with the real path on your computer and replace 'version' with the version number of your installed JRE/JDK...

Comment: Thanks .. I am not building it for java, so no need of `JRE/JDK`

Comment: JRE is required for eclipse itself, you MUST install it!

Comment: Yes, you need a JRE to run eclipse, if you are not programming in Java you won't need the JDK, but the JRE is required.  Check here https://eclipse.org/downloads/ in the lower right for the HINT